# Is the analyte included in the ionic strength equation?

Tags: solubility, solutions, analytical-chemistry, ions

I don't quite understand the calculation for ionic strength of a solution. The formula includes the concentration and charges of the ions in solution, however, is the analyte (whatever we're trying to analyze) also supposed to be incorperated into the ionic strength equation?

If so, how would we include it if the analyte has an unknown concentration (which we have to figure out, using equilibrium and ion activity)?

Comment: If an ionic analyte has an unknown concentration then you have more unknowns and need more equations to solve the problem. You might be able to get around the problem if the analyte concentration is low compared to the other salts in solution.

Comment: Dilute the analyte and/or work at high ionic strength so you can neglect the contribution by the analyte. Once you have an approximate concentration of the analyte from the analysis, check whether neglecting its contribution made sense.